Is there a recommended day to send a cold email or is it better to send it as early as possible?
I've always known that it's best to send cold emails to potential postdoc supervisors on Monday morning. Now I find myself in the situation where I've found a professor who lists a postdoc vacancy on his updated website. Today is Tuesday, do I send an email tomorrow, which is Wednesday, or do I wait until Monday morning?

I'd actually say Monday morning is not good - too much crud in the email inbox from the weekend. Go send it.

Just send it during business hours any time (but it does not matter compared to the other factors. Rarely people get a bit annoyed by late-night emails)

As a professor who gets daily cold emails about postdoc positions.... it doesn't matter. If I am actively looking for a postdoc (or a potential one), I will see it pop up and open it. If I am not, I will ignore it and maybe look at it later. Being a very research active faculty, my job is not M-F, 9-5, it's pretty much every day to some degree.

I would say send one email, and after one week send another reminder. The day/time doesn't' matter. It is unlikely that a professor missed 2 emails.

I disagree. If I am not interested the first time. I am less interested the second time, and potentially annoyed. I have never decided to hire or interview anyone after the ubiquitous "gentle reminder". It's a cold email. What are you reminding the faculty about?

you presumed that the first email would always be read by a professor. Send a reminder is just a way to make sure it is read. At least for me, the first email maybe missed, or read then disrupted by other things, so that I do not reply. If an application is marginal, then one further email may help to have a reply.

Yes, that is the presumption based on my experience in research both as a grad student looking for a postdoc and as a faculty. Faculty who are looking for postdocs will open all of those emails. Those that are not, won't. On a slow day I will politely reply to those requests and wish them luck with their search. Especially when I see someone desperately emailing me with their 2nd or 3rd gentle reminder. Perhaps this courtesy makes people feel like the reminders work, they really don't, the outcome is still the same.

I give this advice not in a way to disparage those trying hard to find a postdoc, because I know it is a difficult task and very stressful. I say it so they can navigate this process much easier. Send out the email, then move on. It is more efficient.
